# Vue Laravel : Roles, Permissions and User Management

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-permission

I am currently using Vue JS + Axios + Laravel architecture to make a dashboard app.

I need to have user with different roles and permissions while hiding some sections of my menu bar depending on the profile (I use Vuetify dashboard by CreativeTim).

I have seen that there is Spatie add on which handle roles and permissions but I am not sure wether the choice of this addon is relevant in a context of headless architecture ?

Can you please advise how you would structure a such architecture versus the requirement ?

Comment: I use Voyager (https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) personally. This is quite an _open to opinion_ question that's very likely going to be closed on here.

Comment: @Stuart does it use VUE ?